# Does every character from group factor through largest central subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms

Let $G$ be a coonected reductive algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $A_G$ its largest $\mathbb{Q}$-split central torus over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $X(G)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the addtive group of homomorphisms $\chi: G \to GL(1)$ that are defiend over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then I am wondering why $X(G)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a free abelian group of rank $k$. I know such $\chi$ factor through $G/[G,G]$. But how can we relate it with largest central subgroup $A_G$?

Comment: "largest central subgroup over $\mathbf{Q}$": this is called "center" and is a $\mathbf{Q}$-defined subgroup. If you mean $\mathbf{Q}$-split, you'd better use a terminology accordingly, such as "largest $\mathbf{Q}$-split central torus".

Comment: You're asking why the dimension of the largest central split torus equals the dimension of split characters. But there are easy counterexamples to this.

Comment: presumably the word reductive is missing, otherwise there are easy counterexamples such as the group of uppertriangular matrices.

Comment: @YCor, Sorry. As Peter commented, I dropped the word 'reductive' on $G$.

Comment: In the reductive case it's still false, if $G$ is not assumed connected (hint: find a nonabelian reductive group whose unit connected component is a central torus and whose finite group of components is abelian). In the case of a connected reductive group, it becomes true, but it sounds like an exercise level: in this case the abelianization is quotient of the connected center by a finite subgroup.

Comment: @YCor, Thank you. Your comment might be what I expected. But I can’t prove ‘abelianization is quotient of the connected center by a finite subgroup.’ Would you sckech the proof for me? Or would you give a reference where I can find the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every connected reductive group $G$ is a product $Z\cdot G'$ where $Z$ is the connected center of $G$ and $G'$ is the derived group of $G$; moreover $Z\cap G'$ is finite. This is a standard result. See for example 19.25 or 21.61 of Milne, Algebraic Groups, CUP 2017.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the very one I was looking for.